# Android - Delete an item from recycler view outside of adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a socket.io chat application . And I have to remove an item from recycler view outside of adapter .

I mean i don't know its position .

I'm trying to update an item in recyclerview but i don't know how .

Is it possible with TAGs ?

Comment: Well if you need to update/delete and item from list you have to know the position of the item, if you have position I can tell you how to update/ delete an item from list

Comment: Display your RecyclerView and Adapter so that I can assist you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is call .notifyDataSetChanged() after removing an object from your list.

For example:

```
listOfObjects.remove(0); // remove the object from the list, use your index here
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This second line will notify the adapter that your list has changed and it should update the RecyclerView with the latest data (meaning the row corresponding to your deleted object should disappear).